# How can I create MKTileOverlay dynamically according to specific URLs from an NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, mktileoverlay

I have an *NSDictionnary* inside an *NSMutableArray* (**dateArrayURL**)

It looks like this :

```
dateArrayURL: (
    {
    date = "2016-10-04 13:00:00 +0000";
    urlImage = "http://www.xxx/XX/XX.jpg";
},
    {
    date = "2016-10-04 12:45:00 +0000";
    urlImage = "http://www.xxx/XX/XX.jpg";
},
    {
    date = "2016-10-04 12:30:00 +0000";
    urlImage = "http://www.xxx/XX/XX.jpg";
},
    {
    date = "2016-10-04 12:15:00 +0000";
    urlImage = "http://www.xxx/XX/XX.jpg";
},
```

Note that the URL Images are different for each dates.

Now I would like to build an MKTileOverlay for each date/URL I have in my MutableArray with the following method :

```
tileOverlay = [[MKTileOverlay alloc] initWithURLTemplate:urlTemplate];
```

Should I loop for each of my element in the Array, and create an MKTikeOverlay with the appropriate URL?
How can I do this, I'm stuck at accessing elements in the dictionary/array.

Comment: Hint to loop: `for (NSDictionary *aDict in dateArrayURL){NSString *urlStr = aDict[@"urlImage"]; NSLog(@"urlStr: %@", urlStr);}`

Comment: Ok I now loop throw each of my URL from the Dictionary. What I need is to dynamically create an array of MKTileOverlay initialized during the loop with each URL.

Comment: `NSMutableArray *allTileOverlay = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; for (...){{MKTileOverlay *anOverlay = [[MKTileOverlay alloc] initWithURLTemplate:urlStr]; [allTileOverlay addObject:anOverlay];`}`?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, I don't know why I was confused, I need more practice with Arrays/Dictionnary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is solves thanks to @Larme who helped me in the comments.